# Compilation error without the @

Tags: c#, escaping, compiler-errors

If I do this

```
movies = new List<string>();
movies.Add("t:\Alistair.flv");
```

I get error in VS2010

> Unrecognized escape sequence

However when I do this

```
movies = new List<string>();
movies.Add(@"t:\Alistair.flv");
```

There is no error, why?

Comment: backslashes start escape sequences, however '\A' is not a valid one, try 't:\\Alistair.flv'. ('\\' is a literal backslash).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the MSDN documentation

> The @ symbol tells the string
>   constructor to ignore escape
>   characters and line breaks

What happens is that when you're using @ character compiler will think backslash as a backslash instead of start of special escape sequence like `\t`. Unfortunately in your case that kind of escape sequence doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

Your first example:

```
"t:\Alistair.flv"
```

Here the compiler tried to parse `\A` as a escape sequence but can't understand it.

The second one

```
@"t:\Alistair.flv"
```

Tells the compiler to treat the string verbatim, so ignore any escape characters.

This one will also work, since \\ is the escape char for backspace:

```
"t:\\Alistair.flv"
```

The tehnical details regarding this can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You get the error because of the backslash. You could also double-up the backslash to escape the backslash:

```
movies.Add("t:\\Alistair.flv");
```

See also Jon Skeet's answer here:

- [What does an @ before the start of a string literal mean?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/12/what-does-an-before-the-start-of-a-string-literal-mean.aspx)

> A string literal such as `@"c:\Foo"` is called a verbatim string literal. It basically means, "don't apply any interpretations to characters until the next quote character is reached". So, a verbatim string literal can contain backslashes (without them being doubled-up) and even line separators. To get a double-quote (") within a verbatim literal, you need to just double it, e.g. @"My name is ""Jon""" represents the string My name is "Jon". Verbatim string literals which contain line separators will also contain the white-space at the start of the line, so I tend not to use them in cases where the white-space matters. They're very handy for including XML or SQL in your source code though, and another typical use (which doesn't need line separators) is for specifying a file system path.

And this article by Jon Skeet here:

- [Strings in C# and .NET](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Strings.aspx)

Comment: That's not really part of my book - it's just an article on the book's web site.

Answer (score 1):

Because when using `@' character you tell the compiler to take the string as is, you have to know that no escaping characters can be included then.

And about the error

```
Unrecognized escape sequence
```

the compiler means it does not understand what you mean by `\A` since it is not one of the list that contain:

- `\\ = \`
- `\n = New line character`
- `\t = Tab`

and there is more, these are called escape characters, and they are not taken literally, rather they have special meanings.

Answer (score 1):

The backspace character, \, indicates that there is a special character to be processed. Eg. If you have \r\n it will add a carriage return and new line to the string.

The @ symbol basically tells it to take the backslash as is.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
movies.Add("t:\\Alistair.flv");
```

Info here : [Using Strings on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228362%28VS.80%29.aspx) (see "backward slash")

Answer (score 0):

See here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe(v=vs.71).aspx

\A is processed as an escape sequence (the \ marks this).  The use of the @ symbol tells the compiler to treat the \ character as a \ character and not the start of an escape sequence.  \A is not a valid escape sequence hence the error.